# Change skin color automatically

Tags: slack

I would like to be able to change the skin colour of my emoticons on slack, to pick a random one.

I haven't found anything that would do it, neither internal to slack nor external.

Have I not looked hard enough?
Otherwise, is this achievable through a custom plugin/module/whatever-it-s-called-in-slack ?